# What does "Kooing" mean?

Tags: meaning

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081226070704AAhqTFt;

> Maybe its the sound like a Kooing, like a little baby would make?

What does *Kooing* mean in this context? Is *Koo* a word or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cooing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coo) is making noises like a pigeon, or if a person is meant, it usually appears in the phrase *billing and cooing* which means talking or behaving in an amorous way: The love-birds were *billing and cooing*.

Comment: Babies making cooing noises - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yCSrb26MLc

Answer (score 3):

In context I think the writer meant "cooing".